# Hash keys encoding: Why do I get here with Devel::Peek::Dump two different results?

Tags: perl, encoding, hash, key

Why do I get here with Devel::Peek::Dump two different results?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';
use Devel::Peek;

my %hash1 = ( 'müller' => 1 );
say Dump $_ for keys %hash1;

my %hash2;
$hash2{'müller'} = 1;
say Dump $_ for keys %hash2;
```

---

Output:

```
SV = PV(0x753270) at 0x76d230
  REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x759750 "m\303\274ller"\0 [UTF8 "m\x{fc}ller"]
  CUR = 7
  LEN = 8

SV = PV(0x753270) at 0x7d75a8
  REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (POK,FAKE,READONLY,pPOK)
  PV = 0x799110 "m\374ller"
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 0
```

Comment: Are you certain you source has the exact same bytes for both keys?

Comment: Same thing for me: I have exactly the same output as you. Copying your code from the browser or typing the umlaut myself gives the same result. The comparison between both hashes works nonetheless: `say 'Found!' if exists $hash2{ (keys %hash1)[0] }; # outputs 'Found!'`

Comment: both `ü` written with the `ü` key from the keyboad.

Comment: btw, `say Dump ...;` should be `Dump ...;`.

Comment: Opend here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443863/getting-encoding-error-when-using-hash-keys-to-write-xml-files-with-xmllibxml a related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those scalars contain exactly the same string. The only difference is only in how the string is stored internally.

My guess is that the key is normalised to make comparisons easier when trying to locate the key in the hash.

Comment: I tried to write a `xml` file with `XML::LibXML` from a hash. When I write the hash-entries in the `$hash{key}...` mode I get error-messages and the script dies:  <error : string is not in UTF-8  
encoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xFC 0x6C 0x6C 0x65  
I/O error : encoder error  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<my_bibliography>  
  <author author="m>

Comment: @sid_com, This is not the place to ask new question, and your question is extremely unclear. Please post it in the appropriate place, and provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443863/getting-encoding-error-when-using-hash-keys-to-write-xml-files-with-xmllibxml

Comment: @sid_com, Thanks, that was much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, I believe ikegami response is correct. I just wanted to add some observations with some code.

I ran the following code through 5.10 to 5.15 and the behavior is consistent.

```
use utf8;
use Test::More;

{
    my %h = ('müller' => 1);
    my $k = (keys %h)[0];
    ok(utf8::is_utf8($k), 'UTF-8 Latin-1 hash key has SvUTF8 set');
}

{
    my %h = ('müller' => 1);
       $h{'müller'} = 2;
    my $k = (keys %h)[0];
    ok( ! utf8::is_utf8($k), 'UTF-8 Latin-1 hash key does not has SvUTF8 set after assignment');
}

{
    my %h = ('☺' => 1);
       $h{'☺'} = 2;
    my $k = (keys %h)[0];
    ok(utf8::is_utf8($k), 'UTF-8 (> Latin-1) hash key has SvUTF8 set after assignment');
}

done_testing;
```

If the second test is expected, it would be the first silent downgrade I'm aware of. I guess p5p has the final answer whether or not this is a optimization bug or expected behavior. (sv_dump looks like a optimization (POK,FAKE,READONLY,pPOK))